# How to POST both normal JSON data and multiple files to Spring MVC controller through single Ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I am trying to create a form page consisting of both normal HTML form fields like text boxes, dropdown lists, checkboxes, etc. along with multiple HTML file elements.

Is it possible to `POST` both the normal JSON data that is built from the normal HTML elements and also the multiple files that are selected to the Spring MVC controller through a single Ajax request?

Is it possible to append stringify-ed JSON object to JavaScript's `FormData` object?

I'm trying to create a form as shown in the image below:-

[image]

Following is the JavaScript code that I'm trying onclick of **submit** button :-

```
function submitMyForm() {
function MyFormData(arrOfCityVisitData,arrOfUploadDocsData) {
    this.citiesVisitedData = arrOfCityVisitData;
    this.uploadDocsData = arrOfUploadDocsData;
}

function CityVisitData(intStateID,intCityID,strVisitDate,strVisitRemarks,intRecID) {
    this.stateID = intStateID;
    this.cityID = intCityID;
    this.visiteDate = strVisitDate;
    this.visitRemarks = strVisitRemarks;
    this.recID = intRecID;
}

 function UploadDocsData(strFileName,strUploadDocsRemarks,intRecID) {
    this.fileName = strFileName;
    this.uploadDocRemarks = strUploadDocsRemarks;
    this.recID = intRecID;
}

var arrOfCityVisitData = new Array();
var intVisitDataTblRowCount=document.getElementById("citiesVisitedByDateTbl").rows.length-1; // 1 static header row
for(var i=0;i<intVisitDataTblRowCount;i++) {
    var cityVisitData = new CityVisitData(parseInt(document.myForm.visitedState[i].value,10),
                                            parseInt(document.myForm.visitedCity[i].value,10),
                                            document.myForm.visitDate[i].value,
                                            document.myForm.visitRemarks[i].value,
                                            (document.myForm.visitRecID[i].value!=="") ? parseInt(document.myForm.visitRecID[i].value,10) : -1);
    arrOfCityVisitData[i]=cityVisitData;
}

var arrOfUploadDocsData = new Array();
var intUploadDocsTblRowCount=document.getElementById("uploadDocumentsTbl").rows.length-1; // 1 static header row
for(var i=0;i<intUploadDocsTblRowCount;i++) {
    var uploadDocData = new UploadDocsData(document.myForm.uploadDocsFile[i].value,
                                            document.myForm.uploadDocsRemarks[i].value,
                                            (document.myForm.uploadDocsRecID[i].value!=="") ? parseInt(document.myForm.uploadDocsRecID[i].value,10) : -1);
    arrOfUploadDocsData[i]=uploadDocData;
}

var formData = new FormData();
for (var i = 0, len = $('input[type=file]').length; i < len; i++) {
    if($('input[type=file]')[i].files[0]) {
        formData.append('file'+i, $('input[type=file]')[i].files[0]);
    }
}
alert(JSON.stringify(new MyFormData(arrOfCityVisitData,arrOfUploadDocsData)));
formData.append('myFormData',JSON.stringify(new MyFormData(arrOfCityVisitData,arrOfUploadDocsData)));
console.log("form data " + JSON.stringify(formData));

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/springcrud/ajax/processFormData.do',
    data: formData,
    headers: { 
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
    },
    //enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
       console.log(data);
    }
});}
```

And following is the Spring MVC controller class's request handler method :-

```
@RequestMapping(value="/processFormData.do",method=RequestMethod.POST,headers = {"Content-type=application/json"})
@ResponseBody
public String processFormData(@RequestBody MyFormData myFormData) {
    System.out.println(((myFormData.getCitiesVisitedData()).get(0)).getVisiteDate());
    return "ajaxTrial";
}
```

And currently this code is throwing **415 (Unsupported Media Type)** error in the browser. What changes are to be done to the above code so that files can be uploaded along with normal form data through jQuery ajax request?

Comment: Yes, but the question is a bit vague. Please, add some code so that we can see what exactly you have in mind.

Comment: What am I doing wrong in the above code? Does JavaScript's `FormData` support this way of POSTing form data along with files at all ? And across Firefox, Chrome & IE 10+ browsers?

Comment: The controller expects JSON, but you don't send JSON. Anyway, the easiest solution is to just submit the form. Is there a particular reason why you want to send JSON?

Comment: Yes @zeroflagL i want to handle the whole form submission using jQuery Ajax request & response. And yes the alternative way is much easier i.e., I could submit the form without jQuery & Ajax and could easily get the files along with other form data on the server side. How to send both - form data in JSON form & files data in the same jQuery Ajax request to the spring request handler method?

Comment: If you really want to send both at once then you would have to encode the JSON data into a form field and decode and deserialize it manually in the controller. Or you send only JSON and encode the files into a JSON property. No matter how you do it, it's a huge effort.

Comment: So, will it be a good (and efficient) idea to fire 2 jQuery Ajax requests to achieve this i.e., one ajax request for uploading the files and the another one for posting other form data?

Comment: If we assume that uploading a file takes at least a few seconds, then a second request won't introduce a noticeable performance degradation. Plus: If the data a user enters contains errors - e.g. wrong date format - those can be handled without having to wait for the files to upload.